# Regex to find content not in quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find parameters outside quotes (Single ou Double)

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO Notifify (to_email, msg, date_log, from_email, ip_from)
VALUES
    (
        :to_email,
        'test teste nonono',
        '2013-02-01 10:48:27',
        'bar@foo',
        :ip_from
    )
 ";

  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all('/:[A-Za-z0-9_]*/', $sql, $matches);
```

The above code will produce the follow result,

`print_r($matches);  // array(:to_email, :48, :27, :ip_from)`

And I want only:

```
:to_email
:ip_from
```

Comment: Just remove the `0-9` from pattern.

Comment: Are you expecting any escaped quotes (`'O\'Reilly'`)? Can there be newlines inside quoted strings?

Comment: But I can have alphanumeric parameters

Comment: what about this: `/\s+:[A-Za-z0-9_]*/`? close enough?

Comment: @TimPietzcker not. Because the variable content are sanitized with `htmlentities` and `nl2br`

Comment: @cha0site at the point! Make a answer, the I will accept! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'/^\\s*:[A-Za-z0-9_]*/m'
```

Should do the trick, checking for beginning of line and white-space and make sure the RegEx query is set to multiline.

**edit**

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^\\s*)(:[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/m', $sql, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This uses the passive non-capture group (?:) which puts the proper results, without the space padding into a sub array of the matches variable at index 1.

Comment: I cannot confirm this at all - is your `/m` supposed to be a modifier? Why is it enclosed in `'`'s?

Comment: @h2ooooooo - The m is the multiline modifier, the regex string starts and ends with /, the modifiers come after the last /. You could always go to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ to verify http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fd6ad6f70b771e44e6374525f3b2b735ccb89fa

Comment: @LastCoder I see - weirdly enough it didn't work in Regexr or Regex101.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative look-behind. This way you will match exactly what's needed.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w):[a-z0-9_]+/', $sql, $matches);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iV5tLP)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
/\s+:[A-Za-z0-9_]*/
```

It's not very rigorous and might fail for more complex examples like like tennis scores (`15 : 30`) but is probably good enough for your needs.