# Match alphanumerics, except only numbers

Tags: regex, string-matching

The original question that gave the idea behind this particular regex is [Regex to find content not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14647560/1190388).

Let's just modify the original sample a little bit:

```
INSERT INTO Notifify (to_email, msg, date_log, from_email, ip_from)
VALUES
    (
        :to_email,
        'test teste nonono',
        :22,
        :3mail,
        :ip_from
    )
```

I know that variables starting with numerals are not allowed in any programming language, but that doesn't mean we can't have scenarios where we need to match just `:to_email` or `:3mail` and `:ip_from` and not `:22`.

How do we proceed? Me and my friend tried it(theoretically only) this way ->

- Store all string in a set
- Subtract the set that contains only numbers

For online testing, I am using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which programming language do you use, but why can't you just check if the line match:

```
^\s*:[0-9]+,?\s*$
```

and just take unmatched lines?

Answer (score 0):

lookaheads will work here

```
\b(?=\d*[a-z])\w+\b
```

as will

```
\b\d*[a-z]\w*\b
```