# Regex to find pattern NOT enclosed in quotes

Tags: c++, regex, c++14

I need to find a pattern in a string (e.g. character '}' or anything else) but this pattern may occur inside a quoted string and, naturally, I don't want my regex to capture it.

Example:

```
bla bla } bla bla      <-- Capture.
bla "bla bla" } bla    <-- Capture.
bla bla } "bla bla"    <-- Capture.
bla "bla } bla" bla    <-- DON'T capture.
bla } bla "bla } bla"  <-- Capture the first, but DON'T capture second.
```

I need to accomplish this using C++14 `std::regex` (so no lookbehind).

I gathered some inspiration in the links below but none fully solves my problem and I assume I am not being very clever to solve it myself:

- [A regex to detect string not enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324749/a-regex-to-detect-string-not-enclosed-in-double-quotes)
- [Regex to find content not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647560/regex-to-find-content-not-in-quotes)
- [Regular Expressions Quick Start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) (and sublinks)
- [using regex to replace words not enclosed in <> signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235787/using-regex-to-replace-words-not-enclosed-in-signs)
- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

As you can see, no much about C++ regexes and even considering PHP, Javascript, Perl, etc. I cannot find an answer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you match them to collect extracted braces. Are you removing them or replacing with something? Another question is, do you need to support escaped quotes? What do you need to turn `bla \\"} bla "bla "bla } \"bla\""` into?

Comment: What do you want to do for (e.g.) `bla } bla "bla } bla" bla } bla`? Capture 1st and 3rd?. In that case, you _may_ have to loop/parse even with a regex that do the quoted/non-quoted case ala your first link

Comment: If you need to remove those patterns outside of quotes in strings without escape sequences, it becomes a very simple task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @WiktorStribiżew. This pattern simply tells me to stop, I don't really need to process it (no removes nor replacements). Well... there can actually be escaped quotes _inside_ quoted text, but not outside.

Comment: Aha, then I suggest doing it like this: 1) remove all substrings inside quotes, try a simple `regex_replace` with `std::regex reg("\"[^\"]*\"")` pattern, and then 2) check if `{` or `}` is present in the resulting string. If it is a single char, you do not even need a regex for the second operation.

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey. Yes, you're correct. I'd have two matches that I could iterate over if needed (but actually I don''t need - I just need to know they occur). The point is to reach a regex that matches my pattern only if not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: I'll give your suggestion a try. I am only cautious about performance since this code must run an a somewhat constrained embedded system. I'll tell you in minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Does this **have** to be regex? Why don't you just walk the text 1 char at a time?

Comment: I would avoid regex in this case if it's a constrained system. Regex does not support context based matching, and hacking it to do so will be far more expensive than normal. You should stream the text, and parse it yourself. (Or with a parse API that supports streaming if you are using a standard format)

Comment: Could you extract a vector of pointers to the regions of the text that occur **outside** quotes (easier to detect) and then search the text regions pointed to in that vector?